# Angular2 subsequent counters

Tags: angular

I have three functions. First function i.e. `Start()` is called on a button click event. `start()` calls another function `startFilling()` after specific seconds set by `counter1` (*this counter decrements and I show it on my template*). `startFilling()` should call another function `checkCorrectness()` after specific seconds set by another `counter2` (*this counter also decrements and I show it on my template*).

My HTML:

```
<!-- Show counter -->
<div align="center" style="margin-bottom:1cm;" *ngIf="counter1">
    <h5>Countdown {{counter1}}</h5>
</div>
<div align="center" style="margin-bottom:1cm;" *ngIf="counter2">
    <h5>Countdown {{counter2}}</h5>
</div>
```

My code looks like following:

```
counter1=5;
counter2=null;
myCounter1: any;
myCounter2: any;

start(){

    /* Set the counter to fire the startFilling() function after specific seconds */
    let timer = Observable.timer(1000,1000);
    this.myCounter1 = timer.subscribe(t=> this.startFilling(t));

}

startFilling(counter){

    this.counter1=this.counter1-1;
    if(this.counter1==0){
        this.counter1=null;
        alert("Filling finished")
        this.myCounter1.unsubscribe();
        this.counter2=11;
    }

    if(this.level===1 || this.level===2 || this.level===3){

        let timer = Observable.timer(this.counter2, 1000);
        this.myCounter2 = timer.subscribe(t=> this.checkCorrectness(t));
    }

    if(this.level===4 || this.level===5 || this.level===6 || this.level===7){

        let timer = Observable.timer(this.counter2,1000);
        this.myCounter2 = timer.subscribe(t=> this.checkCorrectness(t));
    }

}

checkCorrectness(counter){

    this.counter2=this.counter2-1;
    if(this.counter2==0){
        this.counter2=null;
        alert("Check correctness")
        this.myCounter2.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

**The problem here is:** At a time I want only one counter to be visible on the screen, in my case at some point they both show up. Also, they are somehow overlapping and go into negative.

How can I fix this?

Comment: "At a time I want only one counter to be visible on the screen, in my case at some point they both show up"- can you show us the HTML tempate code?

Comment: I Updated my question. Right now I am trying to move the second timer inside `if(this.counter1==0){...}` Otherwise when it is outside, it just starts executing

Comment: what's the intent of your code? you want to execute counter 2 after the second timer has finished?

Comment: Yes my intent is: First function calls second function after specific time. And second function calls third after a specific time. And as a feedback to user, I show them counter on the screen. Say: user gets 5 seconds to see something (this is part of start()) and then 11 seconds to fill something (this is part of startFilling()).

Comment: Also, kindly check my answer and see if you have any suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would abstract the timer creation method as well as the counter2 duration.

```
counter1 = 5;
counter2 = this.getCounter2Duration();
myCounter1 = this.subscribeToTimer(counter1,this.startFilling);
myCounter2;

// can create both counter1 and counter2 from this function.
// start would be countdown seconds (5, 11)
subscribeToTimer(start,callback){
      return Rx.Observable
      .timer(1000, 1000) // timer(firstValueDelay, intervalBetweenValues)
      .map(i => start-i)
      .take(start + 1)
      .subscribe(i => {
        if(start - i === 0){
          callback();
        };
      })
    }

getCounter2Duration(){
//conditional level checking
    if(this.level===1 || this.level===2 || this.level===3){
      return 11;
    }
    if(this.level===4 || this.level===5 || this.level===6 || this.level===7){
      return 14;
    }
}

startFilling(){
        this.counter1 = null;
        alert('Filling Finished');
        this.myCounter1.unsubscribe();
        this.myCounter2 = this.subscribeToTimer(this.counter2,this.checkCorrectness);
    }

checkCorrectness(){
    this.counter2 = null;
    alert('Check correctness finished');
    this.myCounter2.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code like following and it works:

```
startFilling(counter){

    this.counter1=this.counter1-1;
    if(this.counter1==0){
        this.counter1=null;
        alert("Filling finished")
        this.myCounter1.unsubscribe();

        if(this.level===1 || this.level===2 || this.level===3){

            this.counter2=11;
            let timer2 = Observable.timer(1000, 1000);
            this.myCounter2 = timer2.subscribe(t=> this.checkCorrectness(t));
        }

        if(this.level===4 || this.level===5 || this.level===6 || this.level===7){

            this.counter2=14;
            let timer2 = Observable.timer(1000, 1000);
            this.myCounter2 = timer2.subscribe(t=> this.checkCorrectness(t));
        }
    }       
}

checkCorrectness(counter){

    this.counter2=this.counter2-1;
    if(this.counter2==0){
        this.counter2=null;
        alert("Check correctness finished")
        this.myCounter2.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

If there is any better way of doing, kindly suggest.

Comment: are you changing levels during the countdown, or is it static?

Comment: No I don't change levels but the timespan depends on levels, some levels need more time to finish.

Comment: check out my answer